# "Error: 0x80080005 Server execution failed" while installing Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

While installing Ubuntu app on Windows, I'm encountering this error:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80080005
Error: 0x80080005 Server execution failed
```

How do I install Ubuntu app successfully on Windows?

Comment: Upgrade Windows 10 version. It is fixed in newer versions.

Answer (score 10):

Try these steps:

1. Press <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open "Run" dialog. type: `optionalfeatures.exe` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Scroll to the bottom and uncheck "Windows Subsystem for Linux". Click "OK".
3. Repeat the above steps to re-enable Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Check if it now works.

Answer (score 4):

Try restarting the manager for the linux subsystem by opening command prompt as admin (`cmd`) and running:

```
sc stop LxssManager
sc start LxssManager
```

and then query it to make sure the state is `4`, `RUNNING`.

```
sc query LxssManager
```

Now try to open the Ubuntu app again, if it gives a different error this time, try uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

Comment: `sc query LxssManager` returns nothing, and Ubuntu still can't be run. It seems that the LxssManager is stuck and can't be killed in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue once I installed the Windows 10 May v2004 Update and updated to WSL 2

On running

```
sc query LxssManager
```

No output was printed and the solution by @Jsilvermist didn't work in my case.

So instead I found this answer on Windows Forum [Link to OP](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-error/dd28f58e-869a-4a33-8b7f-95695371cb0d?auth=1). It is recommended that you create a backup of the registry before modifying it.

- Press ‘Win + R’ keys on the keyboard together to open the Run dialog box and type the following into the Run box: REGEDIT
- Navigate to the following registry key:
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LxssManager
- On the right pane, locate Start and set the Value Data to 2.
- Exit REGEDIT, and reboot the machine to see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

I have also checked on [this webpage](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-update-error-0x80080005/07b6e544-a501-4492-851d-83fcb80e8f2f?page=1) some solutions as I did not want to do over fixing manipulations.
I have checked if there were some Windows 10 updates on going on my computer and that was the case : my pc has downloaded the latest version but did not install it yet. I did the installation and now Ubuntu works.