# WSL doesn't run, shows server error

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to install ubuntu 20.04 app from Microsoft store, but it gives error

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80080005
Error: 0x80080005 Server execution failed
```

Apart from that, `wsl` is not responding. When command `wsl` or `wsl -l -v` is typed in command prompt, it hangs for a while and when falls with error server. I've tried to reselect checkbox with WSL in Windows components, reselect Hyper-v, change paging file managing as in other similar issues. Nothing works. How can I fix that?

UPD. I also realized that Lxss Manager service isn't working. It is stopped and cannot be started. On the attempt of start it shows error 577 which is problem with digital signature.

Comment: Did you reboot after the previous  step when you installed WSL2's virtual machine platform and kernel?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, I rebooted after the steps which I've described, but I didn't install wsl2 by myself now, it was in the system already.

Comment: What's your Windows 10 or 11 build number? Newer ones have the wsl command present on the system, but need a `wsl --install` first in order to enable WSL2. It's probably *not* the problem you are seeing, but we should confirm the basics first.  The Lxss manager info may be worthwhile - thanks for updating the question with that.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds its 1903 version with 18362.720. But in any case all `wsl` commands do not work. Did you see the update of the question?

Comment: 1903 is pretty old and would put it around the time of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1142359/1165986) where it was a known problem that was (according to an answer) fixed in the next release.  Can you upgrade?